# Space issue in Lucene.NET C#

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I want to search sentence  which has space in full text search.

Ex: `Tom is a very good boy in class.`
I want to Search the key word "very good".

I'm using white space tokenizer to create/search index. But it is not finding the keyword if it is separated by space.

Code:

```
 Query searchItemQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term(string-field-name, searchkeyword.ToLower()));
```

I've tried with split but it is not working properly.

Do anyone suggest me a solution for this problem?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

Since, you are working with tokenized string, every word is a separate term. 
In order too find a phrase consisting of multiple terms, you would need to use PhraseQuery instead of WildcardQuery. 
Like this:

```
PhraseQuery phraseQuery = new PhraseQuery();
phraseQuery.Add(new Term(string-field-name, "very"));
phraseQuery.Add(new Term(string-field-name, "good"));
```

Note also, that you are using wildcard query. Wildcards in phrase query are a bit complex. Check this post for details: [Lucene - Wildcards in phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088558/lucene-wildcards-in-phrases)

And finally, I would suggest to consider using QueryParser instead of constructing query manually.

Comment: In my application, I need to support wildcards and aggregates (and , or) also. I think phrasequery doesn't support all these things. Do you have any solution with wild card query?           ex:     Query statusQuery = new WildcardQuery(new Term(StatusID, status));
                urlQuery.Add(statusQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);xmlQuery.Add(groupQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);   mainQuery.Add(urlQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
            mainQuery.Add(xmlQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

Comment: You can always combine PhraseQuery with other queries via BooleanQuery. 
If you need wildcards inside phrase query - please check the link in my answer above for further guidance.