# Solr "starts with" and "phrase" index

Tags: solr, indexing

I am trying to create an index that'd allow me to do queries based on "starts with" on individual words and partial phrases.

For instance, given the text "`blah blah stuff couple blue drums blah more blah`" (note this is basically a fulltext search for a record using copy fields), I'd like to be able to match the following:

- cou
- couple
- couple blu
- couple blue
- blue drums
- blue dru

It should NOT match a query for "couple drums".

I tried using the "text_general" type, but it doesn't do the partial word queries, such as "cou".

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I also tried an edge ngram filter, but it is not doing phrases how I need them, for instance, a query with `text:'couple drums'` returns results with 'couple' or 'drums'.

```
<fieldType name="fulltext2" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="30" side="front"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Is there a combination of tokenizers and filters that'll accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I just discovered that with the text_general fieldType, I am able to do wildcards for single words and phrase queries for multiple words.  This may be a "wildcards in phrase queries" issue now.  I'm looking into this for Solr 4.0.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088558/lucene-wildcards-in-phrases

Comment: Could you post your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142716/lucene-query-to-match-multiple-words-like-mysqls-like-my-string 
I almost the same problem, thanks in advance

Comment: @rodi It does sound like we're encountering similar issues, but unfortunately I never found an acceptable solution.  We ended up changing the requirements to match what is possible with Solr.  :(

Comment: right now I've decided to split phrase and concatenate it with "?", so "my long phrase is verycomplexxxxx" -> text:my?long?phrase?is?veryco* and it matches. 
What do you think about it?

Answer (score 1):

If your input is actually a phrase, then using Lucene's phrase search will exclude a query like **couple drums** (unless your input includes "couple drums" as a phrase).

You might also want to look at [Stupid Lucene Tricks: Exact Match, Starts With, Ends With](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2012/01/stupid-lucene-tricks-exact-match-starts-with-ends-with.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info Mark.  Unfortunately, I meant a begins with on any give word in a full text field.  I've added more info to the original question to clarify what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build solr-core with [Expose SpanFirst in eDismax](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3925) patch.