# Lucene Query to match multiple words like mysql's "LIKE %my string%"

Tags: php, mysql, lucene

I'm trying to match multiple words in Lucene as I could do in MySQL.

It's harder than I thought:

written in PHP:
my query for perfect match is:

```
$words = explode($words, " ");
(text:(' . implode(" ", $words) . ')
```

but if text is "a bunch of words I wrote", it won't match until I have written everything

Does exist any way to force Lucene to behave exactly like MySQL's like "%a bunc%" and retrieve the hole phrase?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I'm not using Lucene directly, I use Solr as a REST service. So I'm looking for the "plain grammar" to solve this problem like: select?q=*:* and the query is *:* ( select all ) if I have many words in the text field, as told before, I don't find any way to consider them as a unique word.
If it were a unique word, I could do "text:(beginningOfW*)" and it would find it,
If it is a multiple words, If I write "text:(beginning Of W*)" it will find only words beginning with W, and ignore the other words.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to query lucene with "like" operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307890/how-to-query-lucene-with-like-operator)

Comment: @mindas, no I'm looking for "query" like syntax, and my problem is for multiple words

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Lucene is full text search engine API.  I think you are looking for WildCardQuery:

```
Term term = new Term("whichField", "searchString");
Query query = new WildcardQuery(term);
Hits hits = indexSearcher.search(query);
```

Comment: Sorry if I had not specified before, but I was looking for "query syntax, look at EDIT. Thanks very much

Comment: So what are you expecting "text:(beginning Of W*)"  to match? It would match phrases like : beginning Of World or beginning Of Wind etc.

Comment: no absolutely, it would match only text:W* or text:Of or text:beginning, or something similar

Comment: Did you try q= "text:\"beginning of w\"" ?